How do I retrieve JWT stored in a cookie from client component?
TL;DR
How do I access token that is stored in the browser's http-only cookie and display it in my application's layout.tsx?
I've been trying to set up a user authentication for my blog application. So far I have been able to:

register user
send user verification email with the token inside the URL. (this
token has user's email as the payload).
link redirects to verify email api, which verifies the token and updates database
field {emailVerfied: true}
generate a user token with the user role and email as payload
include said token in an http-only cookie

now my browser has the token within the cookie. I want to display contents from said token onto my /app/Blog/Layout.tsx file, Layout.tsx being a client component.
I am just totally lost on what I should do right now. any suggestion would be of great help to me. Thank you so much!
app/Blog/Layout.tsx

"use client";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";
import { ReactNode, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import SearchBar from "@/components/ui/SearchBar";
import Recommendation from "@/components/Blog/Recommendation";
import { TbUserCircle, TbPencil } from "react-icons/tb";
import Link from "next/link";

interface LayoutProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}
export default function Layout({ children }: LayoutProps) {
  const pathname = usePathname(); ///Blog
  const [isHomepage, setIsHomePage] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (pathname === "/Blog") {
      setIsHomePage(true);
    } else {
      setIsHomePage(false);
    }
  }, [pathname]);
  return (
    <>
      <div
        className="shadow-lg shadow-black/30 w-full border-b-[1px] 
      py-2 sm:py-3 flex items-center gap-3 justify-between px-3 lg:px-[3rem] "
      >
        <div className="flex max-w-[70%] sm:min-w-[50%] items-center gap-3">
          <h1 className="sm:text-[1.5rem]">
            <Link href={"/Blog"}>BlogSpot</Link>
          </h1>
          <SearchBar />
        </div>

        <div className="flex items-center gap-3 w-fit">
          <Link
            className="m-0 p-0  border-[1px] bg-item w-fit h-fit px-4 py-2  sm:flex sm:items-center sm:gap-1 rounded-[20px] text-item-foreground hover:text-foreground"
            href="/Blog/new"
          >
            <TbPencil />
            <p className="hidden sm:block m-0 p-0">write</p>
          </Link>

          <Link href="/Auth/Login">
            <TbUserCircle
              className="text-item-foreground h-[2rem] w-[2rem] sm:h-[2.5rem] sm:w-[2.5rem]
           hover:text-white hover:cursor-pointer transition-all duration-300"
            />
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>

      {isHomepage ? (
        <div className="lg:grid grid-cols-3 h-screen">
          <div
            className="col-span-2  lg:overflow-y-auto lg:scrollbar-hide 
       pt-10 pl-[2rem] xl:pl-[8rem] 2xl:pl-[16rem] pr-7"
          >
            {children}
          </div>
          <div className="col-span-1 border-l-2 overflow-y-auto scrollbar-hide pt-16 pl-[2.5rem]">
            <Recommendation />
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div className="pt-10 m-auto w-[90%] sm:w-[80%] md:w-[70%] lg:w-[50%]">
          {children}
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

